# API call for Availity EDI transactions

Tags: api, edi

We are exploring how to call Availity's API to for EDI files such as 278i. Availity has a very simple API example which doesn't specify any EDI transactions. I was able to get the simple demo working (authentication, token, client retrieval) but still clueless about how to do the EDI calls.

I have sent a support ticket to customer service but they replied saying we should have the "view". I'm not sure what that means.

So my question should be, is there some documents/examples for API calls to Availity for EDI transactions? Or if you happen to have non-Availity documents that can be a good reference too.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It looks like you need to generate the EDI transaction and send it via FTP, if I'm reading the EDI guide correctly.

Comment: @Andrew for some transactions such as 837P it will be batch process through FTP, for some it can be REST. Availity is a clearinghouse which seems to provide API access but no example is given.